# After using a variable I can't use it again

Tags: php

For some reason, when I create a variable and use it I cannot use it again, I used it for a foreach and then var dump after ending the foreach and it shows it as an empty varaible

**How I am using the variable**

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4" style="margin-bottom: 25px;">
    <h2><?php echo System::translate("Job listings"); ?></h2>
    <aside>
        <div class="sidebar">
            <div class="related-people">
                <?php if(Session::get('company_using') == $this->company->company_id): ?>
                    <div class="pull-right showHideOptions" style="font-size:12px;">
                        <a href="<?php echo config::get('URL'); ?>company#create" style="color:#127cc3;"><span class="profileIcon"><i class="fa fa-cog"></i></span></a>                                 </div>
                <?php endif; ?>

                <ul>

                    <?php if(empty($this->jobs)): ?>
                        <li><?php echo System::translate("No jobs to show"); ?></li>
                    <?php endif; ?>

            <?php foreach(array_splice($this->jobs, 0,5) as $job): ?>
                <li>
                    <div class="text-box"> 
                        <strong class="name">
                            <a href="<?php echo config::get('URL'); ?>jobs/view/<?php echo System::escape($job->job_id); ?>">
                                <?php echo System::escape(ucwords($job->job_name)); ?>
                            </a>
                        </strong> 
                            <span><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i>
                                <?php echo System::escape($job->job_country); ?>
                            </span> 
                            <span><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i>
                                <?php if(strlen($job->job_description) > '85'): ?>
                                    <?php echo substr(System::escape($job->job_description),0,85); ?>...
                                <?php else: ?>
                                    <?php echo substr(System::escape($job->job_description),0,85); ?>
                                <?php endif; ?> 
                            </span> 
                    </div>
                </li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        <?php var_dump($this->jobs); if(!empty($this->jobs)): ?>
            <a class="btn btn-info col-sm-12" href="<?php echo Config::get('URL'); ?>directory/jobs/<?php echo System::escape($this->company->company_id); ?>/all" id="jobs"><?php echo System::translate("Jobs"); ?></a>
        <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I use a foreach the date echos out fine, but after using it and I var_dump I get:

> array(0) { }

**How I am initiating the variables**

```
//jobs
$jobs = CompanyModel::project_history($company->company_id);

$this->View->renderPage('company/profile', array('jobs' => $jobs))
```

**How I am iniating the `renderPage`**

```
public function renderPage($filename, $data = null)
{
    if ($data) {
        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
            $this->{$key} = $value;
        }
    }

    require Config::get('PATH_VIEW') . '_templates/header.php';

    require Config::get('PATH_VIEW') . $filename . '.php';
    require Config::get('PATH_VIEW') . '_templates/footer.php';
}
```

**And the model with the data (which works when I use it but after using it goes empty**

```
public static function project_history($id = null)
{
    //get the user's employment history
    $database = DatabaseFactory::getFactory()->getConnection();

    //select by session or id
    if($id == null):

        //the sql we're performing.
        $sql = "SELECT * 
            FROM   jobs 
            WHERE  job_user = ? 
                   AND job_enabled = 1
                   AND job_company = ?";


        //run the query
        $job = $database->prepare($sql);
        $job->execute(array(Session::get('id'), Session::get('company_using')));
    else:

        //the sql we're performing.
        $sql = "SELECT * 
            FROM   jobs 
            WHERE job_company = ?
                AND job_enabled = 1";


        //run the query
        $job = $database->prepare($sql);
        $job->execute(array($id));

    endif;

    //what where the results?
    return $job->fetchAll();

}
```

So just to clarify, I iniated my variable with the model and on my html page I can use that variable once then for some reason it empties, any idea what can cause this?

Comment: Use `array_slice` instead of `array_splice`. It returns the sub-array but doesn't modify the original array.

Comment: @BarryTheHatchet I'm getting tired of people posting that when the question contains a little too much code. If they don't understand what's causing the problem, how are they supposed to know how to reduce the code to the minimum necessary?

Comment: @Barmar: Um, reducing the code is indeed the very mechanism by which they're supposed to determine what's causing the problem. That's one of the _first_ steps in basic debugging. The point of requiring an MCVE is that _we're not here to do that legwork for them_. Especially because in almost all cases simply putting in that time will (as well as serving as practice in this vital programming skill) actually solve the problem. No need for anyone else to get involved. Furthermore, remember that questions on SO must be useful to more than just the OP, for them to meet our quality requirements.

Comment: @Barmar That fixed it. Thank you. any idea why I have duplicate copies of the script and on my other copy I am using array_splice but can still use the variable?

Comment: You can still use the variable, it just won't have the elements that you removed with `array_splice`. So if the array originally had 10 items in it, and you splice out 5 of them like this, the next time you use the variable it will only have 5. But in this program the array only had 5 items to begin with, so you emptied it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You write:

```
foreach( array_splice( $this->jobs, 0,5 ) as $job )
```

`array_splice()` **remove** a portion of the array and replace it with something else (and returns removed portion).

So with this action you empty the array.

Use a `for` loop:

```
for( $i = 0; $i < 5; $i++ )
{
    $job = $this->jobs[$i];
}
```

or a simple `foreach` (your array is empty, so you process **all** array elements):

```
foreach( $this->jobs as $job )
```

---

- Read more about [array_splice()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php)